# How to check if date ranges are overlapping in a pandas dataframe according to a categorical column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Let's take this sample dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3],'Date_min':["2021-01-01","2021-01-20","2021-01-28","2021-01-01","2021-01-02"],'Date_max':["2021-01-23","2021-12-01","2021-09-01","2021-01-15","2021-01-09"]})
df["Date_min"] = df["Date_min"].astype('datetime64')
df["Date_max"] = df["Date_max"].astype('datetime64')

   ID   Date_min   Date_max
0   1 2021-01-01 2021-01-23
1   1 2021-01-20 2021-12-01
2   2 2021-01-28 2021-09-01
3   2 2021-01-01 2021-01-15
4   3 2021-01-02 2021-01-09
```

I would like to check for each `ID` if there are overlapping date ranges. I can use a loopy solution as the following one but it is not efficient and consequently quite slow with a real big dataframe :

```
L_output = []
for index, row in df.iterrows() :
    if len(df[(df["ID"]==row["ID"]) & (df["Date_min"]<= row["Date_min"]) & 
              (df["Date_max"]>= row["Date_min"])].index)>1:
        print("overlapping date ranges for ID %d" %row["ID"])
        L_output.append(row["ID"])

Output :

overlapping date ranges for ID 1
```

Would you know please a better way to check that ID 1 has overlapping date ranges ?

Expected output :

```
[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

1. Create a column "Dates" that contains a list of dates from "Date_min" to "Date_max" for each row
2. `explode` the "Dates" columns
3. get the duplicated rows

```
df["Dates"] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row["Date_min"], row["Date_max"]), axis=1)
df = df.explode("Dates").drop(["Date_min", "Date_max"], axis=1)

#if you want all the ID and Dates that are duplicated/overlap
>>> df[df.duplicated()]
   ID      Dates
1   1 2021-01-20
1   1 2021-01-21
1   1 2021-01-22
1   1 2021-01-23

#if you just want a count of overlapping dates per ID
>>> df.groupby("ID").agg(lambda x: x.duplicated().sum())
    Dates
ID       
1       4
2       0
3       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform your datetime objects into timestamps. Then, construct `pd.Interval` objects and iter on a generator of all possible intervals combinations for each ID:

```py
from itertools import combinations
import pandas as pd

def group_has_overlap(group):
    timestamps = group[["Date_min", "Date_max"]].values.tolist()
    for t1, t2 in combinations(timestamps, 2):
        i1 = pd.Interval(t1[0], t1[1])
        i2 = pd.Interval(t2[0], t2[1])
        if i1.overlaps(i2):
            return True
    return False

for ID, group in df.groupby("ID"):
    print(ID, group_has_overlap(group))
```

Output is :

```
1 True
2 False
3 False
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the index as an intervalindex, and use groupby to get your overlapping IDs:

```py
(df.set_index(pd.IntervalIndex
                .from_arrays(df.Date_min, 
                             df.Date_max, 
                             closed='both'))
   .groupby('ID')
   .apply(lambda df: df.index.is_overlapping)
) 
ID
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```